# kinect_aux indexing kinect based on serial no

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm currently using Kinect_aux for multiple kinects. I adjust the device_index param each time I want to switch to another kinect. The point is when I replace the USB connectors or restart the OS the index arrangement changes randomly. So I need to choose a kinect based on its serial no. or any other device specific id.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33679/kinect_aux-indexing-kinect-based-on-serial-no./) by [Amin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2235/amin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 93 on 2012-05-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
boost::shared_ptr<FreenectDevice> device_;
```

then

```
std::string serial_number = device_->getSerialNumber();
```

take a look at how freenect_stack has implemented this:
https://github.com/piyushk/freenect_stack/blob/master/freenect_camera/src/nodelets/driver.cpp

---

Originally posted by [wchar](https://answers.ros.org/users/15436/wchar/) with karma: 61 on 2014-12-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0